# How to form an object order by date which is a property of the object?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

- Snippet 1 by a Pro
- Snippet 2 by me!
- Snippet 3 using underscore.js

Here I would like to know how the 1st snippet is working, how it's adding by date order correctly while used to check both dates?

The unshift() method adds new items to the beginning of an array and returns the new length.
The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).

```js
var obj = [{"name":"ris", "id":3, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":4, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":5, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":6, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":7, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":8, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"}];

var keyHolder = [];   
var keyedObj = [];

obj = _.sortBy(obj, "dt");
obj = obj.reverse();

obj.forEach((m) => {
    var formattedDate = m.dt;
    if(keyHolder.indexOf(formattedDate) == -1){
    keyedObj.unshift({"day": formattedDate});
    keyHolder.unshift(formattedDate);
  }
  
  keyedObj.splice(1,0, m);

});

console.log(keyedObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

**

```js
var obj = [{"name":"ris", "id":3, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"sri", "id":4, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":5, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":6, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":7, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":8, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"}];

var dates = obj.map((dt) => dt.dt).filter((value, index, self) =>
  self.indexOf(value) === index);
dates.reverse();

const orderByDate = Object.fromEntries(
   dates.map(function(dt){
      var filteredObj = obj.filter((d) => d.dt === dt);
      return [dt, filteredObj ];
}));

console.log(orderByDate);
```

```js
var obj = [{"name":"ris", "id":3, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":4, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":5, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":6, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":7, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":8, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"}];

const sortedByDate = _.groupBy(obj, "dt");
console.log(sortedByDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

**

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but `dt` is a string not a date

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you're meaning to ask here. Which steps of snippet 1 are unexpected to you? What would you expect snippet 1 to produce instead?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure yet what you're meaning to ask, I'd like to point out that the "pro" code could be written more concisely, explicitly and elegantly by using more Underscore and starting off with the third snippet:

```js
var obj = [{"name":"ris", "id":3, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":4, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":5, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":6, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":7, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":8, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"}];

const sortedByDate = _.groupBy(obj, "dt");
const keyedObj = _.flatten(_.map(sortedByDate, (group, key) => [
    { day: key },
    group,
]).reverse());
console.log(keyedObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

For added clarity, we can use `_.chain` as well:

```js
var obj = [{"name":"ris", "id":3, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":4, "dt": "Jan 23, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":5, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":6, "dt": "Jan 22, 2021"},
          {"name":"isr", "id":7, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"},
          {"name":"rsi", "id":8, "dt": "Jan 21, 2021"}];

const keyedObj = _.chain(obj)
    .groupBy('dt')
    .map((group, key) => [{day: key}, group])
    .reverse()
    .flatten()
    .value();
console.log(keyedObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```